# **Primary English**Tony thought that his mother <has>/<had> already gone to work

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

Could any English master please help explain why the underline is HAS rather than HAD? Everything happened in the past, so I thought we should use had. Thanks a lot.

Tony loves dogs. He has two dogs. One is called Bobo and the other is called Coco.
Yesterday, he woke up late. After having breakfast, he wanted to feed his dogs. He looked around his house but he couldn’t find them.
Tony thought that his mother _______ already gone to work. His father was sleeping at that time and Tony did not want to wake him up.
He sat on the sofa and started to cry. He missed his dogs very much. His father heard him crying and woke up. About an hour later, his mother came home with his dogs. She took Tony’s dogs out for a walk an hour ago.

Comment: You are correct. It is ***had***.  Whoever said it was “has” is wrong.

Comment: Also the last sentence should be “had taken” not “took”

Comment: But the correct answer is "has"! So can I say the answer is wrong in this case.

Comment: @swong Yes, you can quote us if you like.

Comment: Both are *grammatical*. However, *had* is stylistically far more common in this context, simply because almost all of the verbs in the surrounding sentences use that tense. Using the present tense would be jarring in terms of parallelism. But that's a matter of style and personal opinion, not of grammar.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you, so we could really say "has". I hope my student won't come across this in her real exam because her answer is also "had". We will follow the "had" explanation under normal circumstances.